# Using the Mean Value Theorem to show a function is Contractive

Tags: calculus

The M.V.T theorem says that for a function $f(x)$ defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$, there exists a number $c \in (a,b)$ such that $$f'(c) = \frac{f(b)- f(a)}{b-a}$$

This is equivalent to saying $f(b) - f(a) = f'(c) (b-a)$. If *maximize* $f'(c)$, then we obtain the inequality $$f(b) - f(a) \leq f'(c) (b-a)$$

Taking absolute value on both sides of the above inequality gives $|f(b) - f(a)|\leq |f'(c)| |b-a|$.

A function is *contractive* if there exists a number $\lambda \in (0,1)$ s.t. $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \lambda |x-y|$$ for any $x,y$ in the domain.

As you can see, the inequality obtained from the M.V.T is very close to the definition of a contractive function. The difference being the M.V.T inequality doesn't say it is true for all points in the domain.

**Question:** Suppose I maximize $f'(c)$ and obtain the M.V.T derived inequality. How do I use that to show $f$ is contractive? How do I show the inequality is true for all the points in the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Try to prove that the smooth function $f: [a,b] \to R$  is  contractive if and only if $\sup_{x \in [a,b]}| f'(x) |  < 1 $.

Comment: For the right implication, if $f$ is contractive then $|f'(x)| < 1$ by definition. For the left implication, if $\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x)| < 1$, then...what? How do I know that $f'(x)|x-y|$ is supposed to be larger than $
|f(x) - f(y)|$?

Comment: Use M.V.T to get $c \in [a,b]$ then of course $ | f'(c) | \leq \lambda := \sup_{x \in [a,b]}| f'(x) |  < 1 $

Comment: Okay, but that didn't answer my question. We are assuming $|f'(c)| < 1$. How do we know that $|f'(c)| |x-y|$ is greater than or equal to $|f(x) - f(y)|$? You are saying that if $f'(x) < 1$ for any $x \in [a,b]$, then no matter the points $x,y$ in $|f(x) - f(y)|$ and $|x-y|$, we have the contraction inequality is true

Comment: Note that what I said is a characterization of contraction ! You cant imagine a better answer .  

If you choose $c \in [a,b]$ such that $|f'(c)| = \sup_{x \in [a,b]}| f'(x) |  $ then  $ |f(x)-f(y)|  \le  |f'(c)| |x-y|   $ for all $x,y$

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand how you are able to state your conclusion without proving anything.

Comment: I usually don't prove things which are trivial or they can directly be concluded from definitions ! you should be able to fill out the gaps.

Comment: Well, thanks for the discussion then. Have a good day